# Another RMySQL Windows 7 install issue

Tags: windows-7-x64, rmysql

I am trying to install RMySQL on my Windows 7 Professional x64 machine using R-2.15.1, RTools 2.16 (also tried 2.15), and MySQL 5.5.

I have copied libmysql.dll and libmysql.lib into mysql\lib\opt and \bin.  I have also copied libmysql.dll into R-2.15.1\bin.

I have set Renviron.site properly as confirmed by `Sys.getenv('MYSQL_HOME')` using both the 8.3 nomenclature as well as non-8.3 nomenclature.

Sample output for `Sys.getenv('MYSQL_HOME')` is `"C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/"` (quotes included).  When I use 8.3 nomenclature it also is correct.

Here is the relevant part of my PATH:

> c:\Rtools\bin;c:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\lib\opt;c:\program file\R\R-2.15.1\bin;

I have manually inserted it into the registry in the right location (because the MySQL 5.5 doesn't do that properly - it only puts it under the Wow6432Node) AND I inserted it into the system variables to deal with this error:

> Error in utils::readRegistry("SOFTWARE\MySQL AB", hive = "HLM", maxdepth = 2) :Registry key 'SOFTWARE\MySQL AB' not found

I even tried

```
Sys.setenv('MYSQL_HOME=C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/')
```

However, when I try to install RMySQL I get the following error:

```
checking for $MYSQL_HOME... not found... searching registry...

cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.1/bin/x64/Rscript
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.1/bin/x64/Rscript
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
  http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
Try setting MYSQL_HOME to one of the following (you may have to use the non-8dot3 file name):


ERROR: configuration failed for package 'RMySQL'
```

If I am understanding the error properly, it can't find `MYSQL_HOME`, even though it calls it properly using `Sys.getenv`, is located in the proper location in the registry, AND is a system variable.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue with my Windows 7 x64 installation.

I think the problem is not related to the MYSQL_HOME, but to the registry.
As you can see here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-install-wizard.html
the default location for the registration is not SOFTWARE\MySQL AB but SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MYSQL AB.

I believe the answer is here:
http://martin.von-gagern.net/howtos/20110728-rmysql/